# Pushing a JSON object to array

Tags: javascript, json

I want to push a JSON object to my array; I tried the following code, but right now it is pushing `{"fieldDataType": "test"}` whereas I want to have: `{"S": "test"}` ("S" is what fieldDataType has);

```
var fieldDataType = "S";
p["KeyConditions"][terms[0].attribute]['AttributeValueList'] = [];
p["KeyConditions"][terms[0].attribute]['AttributeValueList'].push(
//{"S": terms[0].value}
  {fieldDataType: terms[0].value}
);
```

Comment: {fieldDataType: terms[0].value} should be {S: terms[0].value}; if "S" is something that changes, you can't use a literal. just make a blank object and use array syntax to add a property on: ob={}; ob['the key name']=terms[0].value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to define an object and set the key using the variable:

```
var data = {};
data[fieldDataType] = terms[0].value;
p["KeyConditions"][terms[0].attribute]['AttributeValueList'].push(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as a string and then parse it, as follows:

```
var pushVal = JSON.parse('{"' + fieldDataType + '":"' + terms[0].value + '"}');
```

This value can then be pushed to the array:

```
myArray.push(pushVal);
```

Inline, it looks like this

```
myArray.push(JSON.parse('{"' + fieldDataType + '":"' + terms[0].value + '"}'));
```